# Can't redirect failed post requests to my error page in Android WebView

Tags: android, redirect, error-handling, webview, connection-timeout

i have this

```
final String linkErrorPage = "file:///android_asset/ErrorPage.html";

public class Callback extends WebViewClient{
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
        webView.loadUrl(linkErrorPage);
    }}
```

and this in my mainactivity.java

```
public class browser extends WebViewClient {
        
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
            webView.loadUrl(linkErrorPage);
        }
    }
```

when i turn my server off i'm expecting to see my error page from the local assets...
if it's a get request everything is fine, i'm seeing the error page... but if it's a post request i'm seeing this page instead:
[image]

how can i redirect to the error page when a post request fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i found the solution!

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new browser(){
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            String string = "net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT";
            webView.findAllAsync(string);
            webView.setFindListener((activeMatchOrdinal, numberOfMatches, isDoneCounting) -> {
            if(numberOfMatches>0) {
                webView.loadUrl(linkErrorPage);
            }

            });
        }
    });
```

though it briefly displays the default error page. if there's a better way i'd like to know it... this is not a perfect solution.